# flex-wrap not working as expected in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

On the homepage of http://www.shopifyexperte.de/ there are two flex-box modules, one under "Kundenstimmen" and one under "Neueste Beiträge...". The inner boxes are supposed to wrap when they go below 220px and not grow above 30% width. This works in latest Chrome, FF and Opera (all on Mac), but in Safari 8.0.5 (Mac) and any iOS browser the boxes never form a row even if there's enough room. They always wrap, each one on a row of its own.

The CSS for the container:

```css
.homepage-testimonial-container {
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 -webkit-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 flex-direction: row;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
 justify-content: space-between;
 -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
 align-items: flex-start;
 margin-top: 1em;
}
```

The CSS for the boxes inside the container:

```css
.homepage-testimonial {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 min-width: 220px;
 max-width: 30%;
 -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

If I disable -webkit-flex-wrap (effectively setting it to nowrap), all boxes line up in a row but eventually overflow the container when the browser window gets too narrow.

Is this some kind of bug in Safari/Webkit or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in Safari. In a separate issue, I tested using the min-width in place of `auto` in lines where you say something like `-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;`.

This question has some info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792851/756329

Comment: The bug seems to be [closed just a couple of days ago](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041), so we can expect a fix in the next release of Safari.

Comment: @JoepMeindertsma - it doesn't matter much since you still have to support +2 years old browser versions..

Answer (score 36):

Set child elements like this seems to work for me

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

Comment: This is probably because recent updates to Safari finally have it working correctly.

Comment: Yeah, Safari 9 pretty much have flexbox working the same as chrome. But that wasn't the case with 8.

Comment: @Dave Let's not get out the band just yet. It's 2017 and Safari still has a long way to go to catch up to any of it's competitors.

Comment: In 2023 this is still broken in Safari. See https://codepen.io/tedmcdo/pen/dygjPX

Answer (score 33):

I had a similar issue in Safari (9.1.3) with the Bootstrap 3 grid system (e.g. col-md-4) in combination with flex. I solved it by setting `margin: 0 -1px;` on the col items and `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the wrapper.

Comment: That was it, a single line that fixes everything under iOS. In my own opinion, this solution is the best because it keeps the flex properties and everything else intact without modifying your overall design and all with min-width and stuff.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Safari rounding pixels without decimals when calculating.

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Still a problem in 2020 and this hack still fixes it!

Comment: thanks - worked a treat on a wp site misbehaving on mac and iPhone

Comment: This did not fix my problem on Safari v. 10.1.2 (2017), which is the current version as of 9/21/20 for Yosemite 10.10.5 running on a MacBook Pro (as native install from purchase with natural updates). At least it didn't break all the other browsers/OS's.

Comment: @AppDreamer I suggest asking a new question regarding your problem - posting a simplified version of your code. It might be a slightly different scenario or CSS combo. I would not want to worry to much about supporting old Safari versions. Apple no longer support Yosemite and would think Safari v. 10.1.2 (or older) in 2020 has way under 1% browser market share world wide.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using Safari 11.0.1 and the bug persists. I use Bootstrap 3 combined with display: flex on my .row elements. I added following to my css to target the column elements. There seems to be something about the width percentages in Safari that aren't being honored correctly.

```
.row [class*=col-]{
    margin:0 -.3px;
}
```

Comment: I just encountered this exact issue (Safari 11, Bootstrap 3). When I use `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on a row with four columns, Safari only displays three columns per row rather than four. Setting negative left/right margins as shown above fixes it.

Answer (score 10):

Setting `flex-basis: 20em` also works, `min-width: 20em` does not.

Comment: Thank you! That's 4 hours of my life I want back! I tried everything else here, but adding flex-basis to my three child objects allowed me to keep wrap-reverse and it works across all browsers now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is indeed a Safari bug. The details are available at the excellent [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#11-min-and-max-size-declarations-are-ignored-when-wrapping-flex-items) page, but to quote it:

> Safari uses min/max width/height declarations for actually rendering
>   the size of flex items, but it ignores those values when calculating
>   how many items should be on a single line of a multi-line flex
>   container. Instead, it simply uses the item's flex-basis value, or its
>   width if the flex basis is set to auto.

So the fix / workaround - as suggested by other answers here - is to set the `flex-basis` to an explicit width rather than `auto`.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this issue again and used 'flex-flow'. Worked like a charm.

```
.row {
    @include flex();
    @include flex-wrap();
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

Comment: best solution imo :)

Comment: Well that's only because you're overwriting the flex-wrap. Flex-flow is a shorthand for flex-direction and flex-wrap.

Answer (score 1):

There are other solutions that work for me.

In the `.row` container `before` and `after` are gets added with these properties:

```
row:before, .row:after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}
```

so setting up the `display: none or display: inline` will solve the problem or setting up the `content: none` will also solve it.

```
.row:before, .row:after {
   display: none;
}
or
.row:before, .row:after {
   display: inline;
}

or
.row:before, .row:after {
   content: none
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/first-posts/26249142)

Answer (score 0):

Remove display: -webkit-box if you have.

Answer (score 0):

I have edit the col-md-6{ flex: 0 0 49.9%} It's working for safari
[image: flex: 0 0 49.9%]