# flex properties not working on safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I am using flex for making a searchbar/input element stay centered and change width as the screen size changes.

This is my html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <h1 class="brandname">Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <form>
            <!-- <div class="search centered"> -->
            <div class="search">
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" />
                    <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}

.search{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 0 1 455px;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 455px;
}

.input-container{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    min-width: 0;
}

.searchbar{
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    min-width: 0;
}


.flex-container > .flex-row:first-child{
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.brandname {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #1f0e3e;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.input-container{
    /*float: left;*/
    /*display: block;*/
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #e3e3e3;
    outline-width: 1px;
}

.searchbar{
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.search button {
    background-color: rgba(152,111,165,0.38);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 0px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #e3e3e3;
    color: white;
}

.search input{
    outline-width: 0px;
outline-style: none;
border-width: 0px;
}
```

and it works in chrome, ie edge and in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ndbomoef/2/) fiddle, but not in safari.

In Safari the searchbar goes above the .brandname element and to the right of it and takes a width of 150px.

any ideas on how to make this work in safari?

One thing that is not working is the the first flex row width of 100% is not working. In safari it is making the two felx-row elements be right next to each other and both of them together are taking 100% of the width.

Comment: Which version of Safari and what OS?

Comment: Yosemite and safari version 10.0.1

Comment: See this can any help - https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: possible guidance: [Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276)

Comment: I think this solves it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986668/flex-wrap-not-working-as-expected-in-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed .flex-row css rules to:

```
.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

and changed the flex-row first child css rules to:

```
.flex-container > .flex-row:first-child{
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

and then it works.

I thought about doing this after reading that flex-wrap is buggy in safari from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986668/flex-wrap-not-working-as-expected-in-safari) SO question which suggests that setting flex-wrap in safari is buggy

Answer (score 0):

Always use the non-prefixed setting last in your CSS rules. In your first rule that would be:

```
.flex-container{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

similar for all other rules.