# CSS3 Flexbox row wrap is not working in iOS 8.3

Tags: html, css, sass

CSS3 Flexbox row wrap is not working in iOS version 8.3 only. As per the suggestion on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360526/row-wrap-in-flex-box-not-wrapping-in-safari#answer-30792851), I have updated my code. But still, it is not wrapping as expected.

`

```
.case-study-list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 0 30px;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        .case-study-item {
            list-style-type: none;
            min-width: 180px;
            padding: 30px 20px 0;
            -webkit-flex: 1 1 180px;
            -ms-flex: 1 1 180px;
            flex: 1 1 180px;
   }
}
```

`
[image: section won't wrap as expected and appears similar to the image]
Please find the link to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elizabethkmathew/pv33717p/3/).
I'm really stuck with this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Seems you missed to add prefix on display property. Safari 9 supports all standard flex properties, with Safari 8 and older you'll need to use vendor prefixes.

```
.case-study-list {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 
}
```

Here are some link's that might help you
[CSS Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)
 [FLEXBOX CHEAT SHEET](https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html)

Comment: I have added the prefix. But still the issue exists.